# How to make flex popover?

Tags: html, css, angular

I have project below looks similiar to that which has popover(ng-bootstrap).As you know all those tooltips,popover etc. aren't flexible which means when you change size of the page it's not getting smaller.To do that I decided to put mat-grid(Which works exactly as I want) inside popover and I expected that would work exactly as I wished.Mat-grid is getting smaller when you change the width of browser and rows are not being seperated after minimum width bound as bootstrap does.Mat-grid isn't working inside popover.How can I make it work?It can be with mat-grid or something else to make popover flexible.

Below you can see the couple of mat-grid layouts.I made smaller that size of the page and if you compare with the actual page size,popover looks very big it should be smaller as google layout is getting smaller.

[image]

Here my demo on stackblitz.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nsqsbi-8xn4rg?file=app/main/GridList/grid-list-overview-example.html

I used bootstrap row and column classes inside popover body.And commented that mat-grid part on stackblitz because its not working

```
<mat-grid-list cols="1" rowHeight="5:1">
  <mat-grid-tile>1</mat-grid-tile>
  <mat-grid-tile>2</mat-grid-tile>
</mat-grid-list>
```

Comment: Hey! Just would like to know whether you are resolved your issue?

Comment: @StepUp I'm sorry,I forgot to give answer but your solution didn't work.Can you send me your edits via my stackblitz demo?

Comment: please, see [this stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nsqsbi-y1myqn?file=app/grid-list-overview-example.css)

Comment: @StepUp I checked.But in yours that context has overflow .Not fit in the popover.I updated my problem also you can check this link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nsqsbi-vhuk6q?file=app/main/GridList/grid-list-overview-example.html . Here on the top grid-list,popover can't be seen compeletely.There's overflow even top of the page

Comment: @StepUp you can move here also.I expalined this problem with more details here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58320803/how-to-make-popover-appeared-compeletely-when-its-on-the-top

Comment: in my view, `overflow` property is used when element's content is too big to fit in its block formatting context. [please see this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow)

Comment: I will try to see your next question, If I have a free time as I am at work now. In my view, this question is already answered. One question, one answer:) [What should I do when someone answers.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: But answer doesn't work thats why I asked another question with more details

Comment: in my view, it works. could you see the above stackblitz example? If it does not work for you, could you what does not work without changing your HTML markup in question. If this works using the declared requirements in question, so it means that answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

It does not resize your pop up window because browser does not know when it should resize your pop up window. You can tell to browser that pop up window should be resized [using `@media` rules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries).

So you need to set `@media` rules and override styles of your `ngb-popover-window` in these rules. So it is necessary to put this code into `grid-list-overview-example.css`

```
:host ::ng-deep .popover
{    
    background: orange;
    border: 10px solid red;
    max-width: 350px;
    max-height: 50px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  :host ::ng-deep .popover
  {
    background: lightpink;
    border: 5px solid lightgreen;
    max-width: 50px;
    max-height: 50px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 205px) {
  :host ::ng-deep .popover
  {
    background: lightgrey;
    border: 5px solid red;
    max-width: 50px;
    max-height: 50px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 100px) {
  :host ::ng-deep .popover
  {
    background: yellow;
    border: 5px solid lightyellow;
    max-width: 50px;
    max-height: 50px;
  }
}
```

where:

- `@media` is a rule which can check width and height of the viewport
- `:host ::ng-deep` is a way to override styles in Angular